# What is the most efficient way to send Arrays and Objects to MongoDB as part of multipart/form-data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am creating a MERN web app. I am sending a post request as a multi-part/form-data. The request has files, arrays, strings, and objects. Based on what I learned, I have to use `new FormData()` then append each field individually. Does anyone have suggestions on how to append the arrays efficiently so each value is saved to MongoDB with a separate key?

Question 1: My arrays should save like this:
0: Apple
1: Banana
2: Orange

Instead the array saves like this:

0: "Apple,Banana,Orange"

Question 2: My objects should save like this:

baskets: {
fruitBasket: "a few fruits",
vegetableBasket: "loaded with veggies"
totalItems: 100,
}

Instead the object saves like this:

[Object, Object]

Question 3:

Is it more efficient to try and convert the data and append it on the front end? Or is it more effective to use backend modification to then send the data into MongoDB?

Thank you in advance!

I tried stringifying the data and it did not work.

Comment: You have to `JSON.stringify` your JSON values before appending them

Comment: Why do you say that? If I use JSON.stringify before appending it does not seem to make a difference to the data entry. Arrays still appear as strings and objects as [object, object] in MongoDB.

Comment: Then post the code that you have, the only way it saves like that is because `toString()` is called on the JSON value